# pyplot imsave gives blank image

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to save an image of a `2D` array with `matplotlib.pyplot` I stumbled upon the `imsave` method, and use it like this:

```
plt.imsave(path, data, origin="lower", format=extension)
```

where `data` is a `N x N` array with the data type `float`. When `extension` is set to `png` everything is working fine. But when I set it to `pdf` or `eps` the resulting `.eps/.pdf` file is blank and no real content is displayed. What am I missing here?

Edit: Using `plt.imshow(..)` and `plt.savefig(..)` I can save a `pdf/eps` file of the image, therefore, I see no real reason, why the `plt.imsave(...)` function should behave like this. I do not want to use `savefig` as it creates unnecessary white/blank boundaries around the real image.

Comment: I cannot answer your question unfortunately. By using something along the lines of: `fig = plt.figure(frameon=False); fig.set_size_inches(1,1); ax = plt.axes([0., 0., 1., 1.]); ax.set_axis_off(); plt.imshow(bla, aspect = 'normal'); fig.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(NullLocator()); fig.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(NullLocator()); plt.savefig('bla.pdf', origin="lower", format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=80, pad_inches = 0, transparent=False, frameon=False)` you will just get a very thin line of whitespace, which is still not what you want, but it is an improvement. :/

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Would you like to file an issue at [GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) yourself or would you like me to do it?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Okay. I create a bug report [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9203).